# What's the action scope of for-loop in ES6?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

What's exactly the action scope of `let` in a for-loop in JavaScript?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let i = 4;
  console.log(i);
}
console.log(i);
```

The external `console.log` throws an error:

> "Uncaught Reference Error: i is not defined"

It proves `i` is in  a block action scope, however, why doesn't the `i` defined in the for-loop throw any duplicate definition error?

Comment: Odd. Apparently `{` introduces a new scope which is nested inside of (rather than being identical to) the scope of the `i` in the for-loop header.

Comment: @JohnColeman You should add this as an answer

Comment: @FrankerZ That is really more of a description of what is being observed rather than an explanation. I think that a good answer would require someone with better knowledge about the language specification than I possess.

Answer (score 4):

The body of a `for` loop (with a `let` variable declaration) has *two* scopes (or LexicalEnvironments): one scope is the *iteration environment*, which contains the variables declared with `let` in the `for` loop declaration, and the inner scope contains variables declared inside the for loop body (after the `{`). This is described in the specification, starting at [13.7.4.7 Runtime Semantics: LabelledEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation)

> IterationStatement : for ( LexicalDeclaration Expression; Expression ) Statement

(this is what a `for` loop which declares a variable with `let` is.)

Evaluating the above eventually gets you to:

> 11. Let bodyResult be ForBodyEvaluation(the first Expression, the second Expression, Statement, perIterationLets, labelSet).

Note that "Statement" can be a *block* (can start with `{` and end with `}`, as most `for` loop bodies do) - this is very important, because a block creates another lexical environment.

[13.7.4.8 Runtime Semantics: ForBodyEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-forbodyevaluation) says:

2. Perform ? CreatePerIterationEnvironment(perIterationBindings).
3. Repeat,

   b. Let result be the result of evaluating stmt.

   ...

   e. Perform ? CreatePerIterationEnvironment(perIterationBindings).

where `CreatePerIterationEnvironment` [creates an environment](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-createperiterationenvironment) containing the variables declared with `let` in the `for` loop declaration:

g. For each element bn of perIterationBindings, do

i. Perform ! thisIterationEnvRec.CreateMutableBinding(bn, false).

ii. Let lastValue be ? lastIterationEnvRec.GetBindingValue(bn, true).

iii. Perform thisIterationEnvRec.InitializeBinding(bn, lastValue).

So, there are two scopes: one created by `CreatePerIterationEnvironment`, and one created by the block that the `stmt` is.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let foo = 'f';
}
```

Here, `i` is contained in the outer *iteration environment*, and `foo` is contained in the inner block, which is a different environment. If you made those two variable names names the same, no error is thrown because `let <variableName>` inside the block creates a variable *scoped to that block*, and does not try to overwrite the variable with the same name in the *iteration environment*.

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 2015 has a particular clause<sup>1</sup> to cover what a `for` loop does when it has a variable defined with `let` in the control structure.

My reading of it is that it is *specifically* designed to provide a separate environment record for the variable within the loop body so that its value in a loop iteration will be seen by nested functions used as call backs - and in the process obviating the need to capture the value of a loop variable in a closure.

Essentially

```
for( let i=0; condition; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

- creates an environment record for the loop body with a binding for `i` set to zero;
- executes the loop body
- creates a new environment record for the next iteration, increments `i` and stores the result in the new environment record for the next loop iteration (if it executes).

Comparing the behavior with block scoping of variables within curly braces is misleading - *the lexical scoping of the variable to the `for` loop body **does not require block braces to be used:***

```js
for( let i = 0;  i < 2; ++i) continue;
console.log( i);
```

So the body scoping of the `let` variable is a language design "special".

<sup>1</sup><sub>Refer to [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57719515/5217142) for technical details of the specification.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared with `let` are not visible (accessible) outside their scope, which explains the error raised by the `console.log` that is outside the for loop).

It also explains why the loop runs three times and prints `4`, the explanation is that the `i` inside the for loop block (the one declared as `let i = 4;`) is different than the `i` in the loop header due to the invisibility that comes with the `let` keyword, i.e., the `i` in `let i = 4;` which is inside the for loop block is not visible in the `for (let i = 0; ...)`, they're different, and so the one inside the block is not affecting the one outside (in the header).